# How to align severity to same width in Boost log

Tags: c++, boost

For example, 'info' and 'warning' have different width, it looks not preety in the log. I want to align them to same width in log.

It seems that I could use customized formatter factory as this article described:
[boost log format single attribute with logging::init_from_stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359921/boost-log-format-single-attribute-with-logginginit-from-stream)

This is another solution by using customized severity level:
[how do I format a custom severity_level using a format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930553/in-boost-log-how-do-i-format-a-custom-severity-level-using-a-format-string)

Besides that, is there an easier way to achieve this by customizing the format string just like printf?

Comment: Did you try `std::setw`? Depending on how you output severity level, setting width to the stream before and after the severity level might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the formatter to something like

```
expr::stream << std::left << std::setw(7) << std::setfill(' ') <<
                logging::trivial::severity << " " << expr::smessage;
```

The width of 7 comes from the maximum possible length ('warning'). You should change it if you use custom severity levels.

Here a more complete example (header files omitted for simplicity):

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

using namespace logging::trivial;

logging::sources::severity_logger<severity_level> s_log;

void init_logging(const std::string& log_dir)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<logging::core> core = logging::core::get();
  boost::shared_ptr<sinks::text_file_backend> backend =
    boost::make_shared<sinks::text_file_backend>(
      keywords::file_name = log_dir + "/l_%Y-%m-%d_%5N.log", // one file per date and execution
      keywords::rotation_size = 512 * 1024); // rotate after 512KB

  // Collect clashing logs
  backend->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(keywords::target = log_dir));
  backend->scan_for_files();

  typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_file_backend> sink_t;
  boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> sink(new sink_t(backend));
  sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
  sink->set_formatter(expr::stream <<
                      "[" << expr::attr<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp") << "] " <<
                      std::left << std::setw(7) << std::setfill(' ') << logging::trivial::severity << " " <<
                      expr::smessage);
  core->add_sink(sink);

  s_log.add_attribute("TimeStamp", logging::attributes::local_clock());
}
```

Comment: I apologize if the code contains any typo or error, I copied and edited from one of the applications I'm working on but I didn't have time to test it in a clean project.